# Updating job status on SauceLabs via Jenkins Sauce on Demand

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, saucelabs

I'm running tests on Jenkins using Cucumber and SauceLabs using the plugin Sauce on Demand.

The integration with Sauce on Demand is working fine, except I'm not able to set Pass/Fail status on SauceLabs.

**WebDriver Instantiation**

```
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName(System.getenv("SELENIUM_BROWSER"));
    desiredCapabilities.setVersion(System.getenv("SELENIUM_VERSION"));
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM,System.getenv("SELENIUM_PLATFORM"));

    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("build", System.getenv("JOB_NAME") + "_" + System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER"));
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability("name", jobName);
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
            new URL("http://"+System.getenv("SAUCE_USERNAME")+":"+System.getenv("SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY")+"@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),
            desiredCapabilities);
```

**Printing SessionID and JobName on log**

```
    String message = String.format("SauceOnDemandSessionID=%1$s job-name=%2$s",
            (((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId()).toString(), jobName);
    System.out.println(message);
```

**Cucumber runner class and log configuration**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    glue = "abc",
    features = "classpath:abc/Login.feature",
    format = "junit:target/surefire-reports/Login.xml")
public class LoginCucumberTest {

}
```

**Jenkins configuration**

[Jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlOi4.png)

**Build result showing the test failed**

[Build result showing the test failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqQfa.png)

**Build Log**

```html
Started by user Eduardo Marques
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@git.sofist.com.br/automatizacao-abc.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git.sofist.com.br/automatizacao-abc.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Jenkins GIT key
 > /usr/bin/git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git.sofist.com.br/automatizacao-abc.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 896524e677f23ff0696d9c0c9deb778e9ec76120 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f 896524e677f23ff0696d9c0c9deb778e9ec76120
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list e1225a75e40d7fc9ab47a3459d4c5e9ae3ee6a15 # timeout=10
Starting pre-build for Sauce Labs plugin
Starting Sauce Connect on master node using identifier: default
Launching Sauce Connect on 172.30.0.123
Sauce Connect 4.3.13 now launched for: eduardomarques
Incremented process count for eduardomarques, now 1
Finished pre-build for Sauce Labs plugin
[workspace] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/maven3.2.2/bin/mvn clean test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building automatizacaoabc 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ automatizacaoabc ---
[INFO] Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ automatizacaoabc ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ automatizacaoabc ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ automatizacaoabc ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ automatizacaoabc ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace/target/test-classes
[INFO] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace/src/test/java/abc/LoginTest.java: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace/src/test/java/abc/LoginTest.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
[INFO] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace/src/test/java/abc/LoginTest.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ automatizacaoabc ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/abc/workspace/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running abc.LoginCucumberTest
SauceOnDemandSessionID=469a6e39f1cc4042885929c26e360340 job-name=Login com usuario valido

1 Scenarios ([32m1 passed[0m)
6 Steps ([32m6 passed[0m)
0m15.918s

Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 16.894 sec

Results :

Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.163 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-24T23:57:12+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/41M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Starting post-build for Sauce Labs plugin
Shutting down Sauce Connect
Decremented process count for eduardomarques, now 0
Flushing Sauce Connect Input Stream
Flushing Sauce Connect Error Stream
Closing Sauce Connect process
Sauce Connect stopped for: eduardomarques
Finished post-build for Sauce Labs plugin
Recording test results
Starting Sauce Labs test publisher
Finished Sauce Labs test publisher
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: It's clear based on the information that you provided that you have a question that you have not asked yet.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin doesn't handle updating the pass/fail status for you. I have successfully been able to update the Sauce Labs Pass/Fail status by using the Sauce-Rest package within my framework.

Here is a link to the Sauce-Rest Repo:

https://github.com/saucelabs/saucerest-java

Here is my working code:

```
import com.saucelabs.saucerest.SauceREST;

    public void UpdateResults(boolean testResults) throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        SauceREST saucerest = new SauceREST(USERNAME, ACCESS_KEY);
        Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        updates.put("passed", testResults);
        saucerest.updateJobInfo(sessionId, updates);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Throwable {
        driver.quit();
        UpdateResults(testResults);
        System.out.println("SauceOnDemandSessionID="+ sessionId + "job-name="+ jobName);
    }
```

Source:

https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/Java-CucumberJVM/blob/master/src/test/java/com/yourcompany/saucecucumberjvm/GuineaPigSteps.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line of code in your *After hooks* for updating the results in saucelabs

`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("sauce:job-result=<passed/failed>");`

`scenario.isFailed()` method will give the status of the scenario in cucumber-jvm.